# Can't use $text with String

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

This code dumped to exception

```
self.staticVars.Model
        .find({shortAddress: {$text : { $search: data.text }}, _town: data._town},{limit: 10})
        .populate('_street _district')
        .sort({house: 1})
        .exec(callback);
```

Exception

```
Can't use $text with String
```

Model

```
shortAddress: {
    type: String
},
```

Index

```
collection.ensureIndex({fullAddress: 'text', shortAddress: 'text'}, { default_language: "russian" },function(){});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text) you cannot specify a field for the text search, it will search across all the indexed fields, so in your case it will search over fullAddress and shortAddress returning documents that match in either of these fields.

Your query would need to be:

```
self.staticVars.Model
    .find({$text : { $search: data.text }, _town: data._town},{limit: 10})
    .populate('_street _district')
    .sort({house: 1})
    .exec(callback);
```

This should now return you the correct data.